How to compare two data from different period in Bigquery
I will need to create a query from a data of visitors who come to a region for certain period of time.  Then, Out of this visitors list I would like to list visitors who has not come from the last 12 months.    Could you suggest how this can be written in BigQuery?
Assume table has field names as follow: visitor_name, visitor's city, date (of record), visited_area.
I queried a list of visitors who come to the area of inteested for the last three years and from this list I'd like to see who has not visited again for the last 12 months.
I was expecting a list of visitors from have not visited the place for teh last 12 months.

Please take a moment and add sample data which helps to explain your question.

An example of data is something like this.  Of course I have several hundreds of thousands of records in our bigquery table that span for a few years.
| Date   | visitor | city (origin) | Visited area |
| ------ | ------- | ------------- | ------------ |
| 1-Oct  | A       | Houston       | 1            |
| 2-Oct  | B       | Dallas        | 2            |
| 3-Oct  | C       | Washington    | 2            |
| 4-Oct  | D       | Philadeplhia  | 1            |
| 5-Oct  | E       | New York      | 1            |
| 6-Oct  | F       | New York      | 1            |
